# Periodic insertions of '-' character while using Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

Every 5 minutes, a '-' character is inputted when I'm running the Windows 10 Pro operating system.

This still occurs when no keyboard is connected, and when all keyboard device drivers have been uninstalled.
(That said, my keyboard is a Filco Majestouch 2, and the Device manager reports that I have two "HID Keyboard Device" devices enabled. For both, the driver is the Microsoft-issued driver version 10.0.16299.15)

This seems to happen regardless of what application is running, but is most obvious when typing or playing a game in which the '-' key is bound to an action.

The issue is present from boot, and is unaffected by restarting. It does not appear to be related to any activity on my part.

Most of my time is spent in Ubuntu 18, which does not suffer from this issue.

Using UIForETW, I tracked keypresses after booting my system with no keyboard connected and opening a Notepad window:

[image: keypress trace]
The relevant text from this trace:

> ThreadId, Virtual key code (Field 1), Key name (Field 2), Time (s)
>
> 6452, 144, < unknown key>, 233.788931940
>
> 6452, 189, -, 233.801680235
>
> 6452, 144, < unknown key>, 233.803025330
>
> 6452, 144,  < unknown key>, 534.803823074
>
> 6452, 189, -, 534.805705281
>
> 6452, 144, < unknown key>, 534.807160578

2 '-' characters were inserted, 301 seconds apart.

Comment: Welcome to SU! Could you provide more detail? Does this happen when using a specific application or any application? Does it happen even if you're not using your computer (but it's on)? Does it still happen after a restart? Does it happen with a different keyboard? If you have On-Screen Keyboard open, does it register the keypress too? (And why two HID keyboards?) Please [edit] your question to provide these details.

Comment: I believe an ETW trace could capture key presses.  I would suggest take a loot at UIforETW. Could offer something.

Comment: @HelpingHand Thanks for your recommendations! I've included a UIforETW trace and some details that will hopefully prove helpful.

Comment: @NiayeshIsky Thanks! I've added as many details as possible. I do not have another keyboard to test with, unfortunately, nor do I know why the Device Manager reports 2 keyboards.

Comment: Thanks for the details, @sentientcabbage. It's interesting that this happens right after reboot. Two things: 1) Your keypress trace is unfortunately very blurry; could you possibly screenshot it again? 2) Can you try the trace again, but this time, before rebooting your computer, can you unplug your keyboard entirely? If you need to log in and you don't have a touchscreen, you can use the on-screen keyboard to type. This should tell you if it's a problem of your keyboard sending incorrect signals.

Comment: @NiayeshIsky I've updated my answer accordingly. The issue still occurs when the computer starts without any connected keyboard (which I find mystifying).

Comment: This is really strange! I looked up the virtual key codes [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes), and key code 189 (0xBD in hex) is of course the `-`, but key code 144 (0x90) is the NUM LOCK key, which is _really_ weird considering you had no keyboard connected...

Comment: [This forum post](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/keys-being-pressed-randomly-help.1232220/) discusses a similar issue, which ended up being a faulty physical wire in the USB connections area. If you feel you've eliminated all software possibilities, you may want to check out your hardware. Specifically, make sure that all your USB devices, USB ports, and anything near that area of your computer case is attached correctly and isn't doing anything weird.

Comment: @NiayeshIsky Thanks for that link! Bizarrely, this issue seems specifically linked to one of my computer's USB ports - when unused, the problem does not manifest. Avoiding this port is solution enough for me right now. If you'd like to post an answer with that link, I'd be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you basically eliminated all software possibilities and the possibility of your keyboard sending the faulty signals, it seems that this is a hardware issue. [This forum post](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/keys-being-pressed-randomly-help.1232220/) discusses a similar issue, which ended up being a faulty physical wire in the USB connections area. So, make sure that all your USB devices, USB ports, and anything near that area of your computer case is attached correctly and isn't doing anything weird.

Comment: Should this not also affect the Ubuntu system too?

Comment: @QuickishFM Good point, though maybe Ubuntu is doing a better job of filtering out bad keypresses, somehow? I don't really know :/

Comment: Personally I think that the random keycode injected every so often is interpreted differently in Windows than it is Ubuntu. Windows processes it as a -, while Ubuntu most likely just ignores it because it might not be directly supported as a keyboard keystroke...

Comment: @QuickishFM Makes sense :) After all, the keycode table I checked is Windows-specific.